# Edit column value if numeric using Awk

Tags: bash, awk

What I would like to do is search for lines where the first column does not begin with 'rs' or 'chr' THEN if those lines begin with a number, add 'chr' to the start of the first column value, otherwise leave as it was.

I have the following code:

```
awk '((!($1 ~ /rs/ || $1 ~ /chr/)) && $1 ~ /^[[:0-9:]]|$/) {$1 = "chr"$1}1' filename > newfilename
```

This is good but attaches 'chr' to all first column values that do not begin with 'rs' or 'chr'. There are some values in this column that I do not want to change and these all begin with letters (a-z). I only want to change the values which start with numbers (0-9).

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question to show some testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that `[[:0-9:]]` is not doing what you expect.  You can `man re_format` for details about bracket expressions. What you probably intended was `[[:digit:]]`. But 99.9% of the time, `[0-9]` will be sufficient.

What about...

```
awk '/^(rs|chr)/{print; next} /^[0-9]/{$1="chr" $1} 1' oldfile > newfile
```

Broken out for easier reading, this is what we're doing:

```
# If the line starts with a marker, print it and move to the next line.
/^(rs|chr)/ {
  print;
  next;
}

# If the line starts with a number, convert it.
/^[0-9]/ {
  $1="chr" $1;
}

# If we're still processing, print the line.
1
```

Note that when you change field contents, awk collapses whitespace.

---

Of course, if you really meant "PREPEND" instead of "append", then the script is quite a bit simpler, because we can assume that any line that begins with a number does not include an "rs" or a "chr" at the start.

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ { printf("chr") } 1' oldfile > newfile
```

And alternately, you didn't say whether you want existing "chr" and "rs" lines to be PRINTED or IGNORED.  The above solution prints them.  To ignore them, simply use:

```
awk '/^(rs|chr)/{ next } /^[0-9]/ { printf("chr") } 1' oldfile > newfile
```